# Adding a default constructor to a base class changes sizeof() a derived type

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, sizeof

I tend to think I have a pretty good grasp of C++ internals and memory layouts, but this one has me baffled.  I have the following test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo
{
    //Foo() {}
    int x;
    char y;
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
    char z[3];
};

int main()
{
    printf( "Foo: %u Bar: %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof( Foo ), (unsigned)sizeof( Bar ) );
}
```

The output is reasonable:

> Foo: 8 Bar: 12

However, this is the very odd part, if I uncomment that simple default constructor on Foo(), the sizeof( Bar ) changes!  How can the addition of a ctor possibly change the memory layout of these classes?

> Foo: 8 Bar: 8

Compiled using gcc-7.2

Comment: Does the same effect happen when using `class` or putting the `struct` into a namespace? I could imagine that there is an interaction with C compatibility.

Comment: @Slava I can reproduce MinGW GCC 5.1.0

Comment: 8 12 in VS2017 all the time

Comment: @NeilButterworth nevermind misunderstood when 8/12 when 8/8

Comment: Maybe because it's no longer an aggregate?

Comment: What if you add a member function that's not a constructor

Comment: Compare the assembly output and see what's different.

Comment: @M.M At least for my compiler (see above) it makes no difference - we get 8/12 with or without it.

Comment: If you remove constructor but add `public:` you will see the same issue, at least with GCC. I think MSVC won't give you this. The things is that once structure starts using C++ features, its stop being a POD type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thats not relevant here

Comment: @Ivan I think youre on the right track, looks like it might have to do with the object no longer being a "POD" after I add a constructor

Comment: @Ivan I certainly don't see any such thing with GCC.

Comment: Also this program causes UB by using the wrong format specifiers

Comment: @NeilButterworth With MSVC? It ignores such things, afaik it does not differentiante `class` and `struct` for example (except for default visibility). The thing is that for C++ there is a difference between a "structure" type and a "class" type. Although actual terminology is different, either POD type or aggregate type.

Comment: @Ivan As I said, with GCC - there is no reason private/public access should make any difference to the size of a class.

Comment: @NeilButterworth There is and you can check it here - https://godbolt.org/g/pg16sG Try adding `private` and see how size changes.

Comment: @NeilButterworth You mean you can't think of a reason  . There's no obvious reason a user-provided constructor should change the size of a class either

Comment: It stopped being standard-layout, and thus stopped being POD, as soon as you had both the parent and child with member variables.

Comment: @M.M I can think of several reasons (for example, as others pointed out, adding a constructor makes the struct not be a POD), but I admit I don't see why that should reduce the size of the object. Adding a public: specification to a struct does not, AFAIK, prevent it from being a POD.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Just think of `memset(foo, 0, sizeof(Foo)` and what it will do with C++ Foo-derived class.

Comment: @Ivan What does that have to do with having a public: specification?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Once structure starts using C++ features it loses C compatibility. It is now forbidden to do some operations on that structure which allows compiler to reduce sturcture size. Compiler cannot do this with structures that look like they were defined in C language because of compatibility.

Comment: @Ivan Unless you can post some part of the C++ Standard that supports what you are asserting, I will simply have to disagree.

Comment: @cHao the issue could be whether `Foo` is POD or not (not Bar, which as you point out, was never POD). And that could be because `Foo` might be shared with C

Comment: I suspect the answer is somewhere at https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#class-types , which specifies the C++ ABI that gcc uses (gcc uses this ABI spec for other architectures besides Itanium)

Comment: The answer is tail-padding. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110347/when-extending-a-padded-struct-why-cant-extra-fields-be-placed-in-the-tail-pad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC follows the Itanium ABI for C++, which prevents the tail-padding of a POD being used for storage of derived class data members.

Adding a user-provided constructor means that `Foo` is no longer POD, so that restriction does not apply to `Bar`.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110347/when-extending-a-padded-struct-why-cant-extra-fields-be-placed-in-the-tail-pad) for more detail on the ABI.