# Is the memory layout of C++ single inheritance the same as this C code?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, inheritance

I'm working with a library written in C, which does inheritance like so:

```
struct Base
{
   int exampleData;
   int (function1)(struct Base* param1, int param2);
   void (function2)(struct Base* param1, float param2);
   //...
};

struct Derived
{
   struct Base super;
   //other data...
};

struct Derived* GetNewDerived(/*params*/)
{
    struct Derived* newDerived = malloc(sizeof struct Derived);
    newDerived->super.function1 = /*assign function*/;
    newDerived->super.function2 = /*assign function*/;
    //...
    return newDerived;
}

int main()
{
    struct Derived *newDerieved = GetNewDerived(/*params*/);
    FunctionExpectingBase((struct Base*) newDerived);
    free(newDerived);
}
```

It is my understanding this works because the pointer to `Derived` is the same as the pointer to the first member of `Derived`, so casting the pointer type is sufficient to treat an object as its "base class." I can write whatever gets assigned to `function1` and `function2` to cast incoming pointer from `Base*` to `Derived*` to access the new data.

I am extending functionality of code like this, but I am using a C++ compiler.  I'm wondering if the below is equivalent to the above.

```
class MyDerived : public Base
{
    int mydata1;
    //...

public:
    MyDerived(/*params*/)
    {
        function1 = /*assign function pointer*/;
        function2 = /*assign function pointer*/;
        //...
    }

    //...
};

int main()
{
    MyDerived *newDerived = new MyDerived(/*params*/);
    FunctionExpectingBase( static_cast<Base*>(newDerived) );
    delete newDerived;
}
```

Can I expect the compiler to lay out the memory in `MyDerived` in the same way so I can do the same pointer cast to pass my object into their code? Or must I continue to write this more like their C architecture, and not take advantage of the C++ compiler doing some of the more tedious bits for me?

I'm only considering single inheritance for the scope of this question.

Comment: Which is part is `C` here?

Comment: @coderredoc the library code. :)

Comment: Ah yes..I see...Good catch @SouravGhosh

Comment: I would wrap the C library into a C++ classes or structs and manage the "C" pointers internally in that wrapper class (make your life easier).  make sure that the C header is wrapped in `extern "C" { }` constructs using the __cplusplus preprocessor define.

Comment: I think you can use `MyDerived` that way but put compile time asserts that validates memory layout. So if by mistake somebody adds virtual functions to MyDerived compilation would fail.

Comment: @AhmedMasud the library is simply too large for me to be able to do that for all of it. However, this question is part of doing that for just one part. They do the `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" ...` parts for me.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was just trying to get to the point about the memory layout, the proper typedefs are in the production code. Nonetheless, I just added the word `struct` to make it compileable.

Comment: It will most likely work so long as you don't introduce a virtual method into Derived.  (Because then the pointer to Derived will point to the v-table and not the first declared member.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Adding a default constructor to a base class changes sizeof() a derived type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914612/adding-a-default-constructor-to-a-base-class-changes-sizeof-a-derived-type) and [When extending a padded struct, why can't extra fields be placed in the tail padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110347/when-extending-a-padded-struct-why-cant-extra-fields-be-placed-in-the-tail-pad) memory layout can change even if you just add constructor to `MyDerived` or make it non POD any other way. So I am afraid there is no such guarantee. Practically you can make it work using proper compile time asserts validating the same memory layout for both structures, but such solution does not seem to be safe and supported by standard C++.

On another side why your C++ wrapper `MyDerived` cannot inherit from `Derived`? This would be safe (as it can be safe when `Derived` is casted to `Base` and back, but I assume that is out of your control). It may change initialization code in `MyDerived::MyDerived()` to more verbose, but I guess that is small price for proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem it does not really matter since the "client" code only cares about having a valid `Base*` pointer: they aren't going to downcast it in Derived or whatever, or copy it.

Comment: OP says in description that library does cast to Derived indeed

Comment: well, that would be undefined behaviour then, since it's not really an instance of Derived.

Comment: no, a "standard layout" object is allowed to be cast to its first member: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout (third bullet point) and the structs of @Cody seems to be standard layout

Comment: I see, thanks. So looks like inheritance from `Derived` is a proper solution then.