# Difference between class and struct with regards to padding and inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

All of the below will be done on GCC 9.1 using [Compiler Explorer](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer), in x86-64, using `-O3`.

I have this code:

```
struct Base {
    Base() {}
    double foo;
    int bar;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    int baz;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return sizeof(Derived);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/OjSCZB

It correctly returns `16`, as I would expect, 8 bytes for `foo`, and 4 bytes for `bar` and 4 bytes for `baz`. This works only because `Derived` inherits from `Base` and so it does not have to pad after `bar` due to `Derived` being a single type containing both `Base` and `Derived` elements.

I have two questions, as below:

**First question**

If I remove the explicit constructor of `Base() {}`, it starts returning `24`, instead of `16`. i.e. it adds padding after `bar` and `baz`.

https://godbolt.org/z/0gaN5h

I can't explain why having an explicit default constructor is any different to having an implicit default constructor.

**Second question**

If I then change `struct` to `class` for `Base`, it changes back to returning `16`. I can not explain this either. Why would the access modifiers change the size of the structure?

https://godbolt.org/z/SCYKwL

Comment: Half a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47914612/560648. I don't know why changing the keyword introducing the base would make a difference though (given that there's no member re-ordering going on anyway so differing member access levels oughtn't come into it)

Comment: Ah thanks! That answer the first question, but not the second

Comment: Re: "It correctly returns 16, as I would expect" -- by definition, the result of `sizeof` is **correct**, regardless of what you expect.

Comment: Hmm yeah it's the access specifier; add `public:`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not a bug.  Aggregates can't have private members

Comment: it seems that padding happens when you mix private/public fields

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This all boils down to whether your type is an aggregate or not.  With

```
struct Base {
    Base() {}
    double foo;
    int bar;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    int baz;
};
```

`Base` is not an aggregate because of the constructor.  When you remove the constructor, you make `Base` an aggregate which, per [Adding a default constructor to a base class changes sizeof() a derived type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47914612/560648), means gcc won't "optimize" for space and the derived object won't use the base's tail padding.

When you change the code to

```
class Base {
    double foo;
    int bar;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    int baz;
};
```

`foo` and `bar` are now private (becauses classes have private accessibility by default) which again means `Base` is no longer an aggregate as aggregates are not allowed to have private members.  This means we are back to how the first case works.

Answer (score 10):

With your Base class you will get 4 bytes of tail padding, and the same with the Derived class, that's why it should normally be `24 bytes` total for the size of `Derived`.

It becomes 16 bytes, because your compiler is able to do [tail padding reuse](http://bryanpendleton.blogspot.com/2011/03/tail-padding-reuse-in-gcc.html).

However tail padding reuse is problematic with [`POD` types](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Data_structure) (all members public, defaulted constructor, etc...), because it breaks common assumptions a programmer would make. (So basically any sane compiler won't do tail padding reuse for pod types)

Let's pretend compilers would use the `tail padding reuse` for POD types:

```cpp
struct Base {
    double foo;
    int bar;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    int baz;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // if your compiler would reuse the tail padding then the sizes would be:
    // sizeof(Base) == 16
    // sizeof(Derived) == 16

    Derived d;
    d.baz = 12;
    // trying to zero *only* the members of the base class,
    // but this would zero also baz from derived, not very intuitive
    memset((Base*)&d, 0, sizeof(Base));

    printf("%d", d.baz); // d.baz would now be 0!
}
```

When adding an explicit constructor to the Base class, or by changing the `struct` keywords to `class`, the `Derived` class doesn't satisfy the POD definition anymore and therefore tail padding reuse doesn't happen.