# Why does mandatory copy elision not apply to potentially-overlapping subobjects?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

## Background

[Mandatory elision of copy/move operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) may be already familiar to many C++ programmers. Examples copied from the linked text. Copies and moves *must not* be inserted by the compiler:

> - In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:
>
> ```
> T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
> ```
>
> This can only apply when the object being initialized is known not to be a potentially-overlapping subobject:
>
> ```
> struct C { /* ... */ };
> C f();
>  
> struct D;
> D g();
>  
> struct D : C
> {
>     D() : C(f()) {}    // no elision when initializing a base-class subobject
>     D(int) : D(g()) {} // no elision because the D object being initialized might
>                        // be a base-class subobject of some other class
> };
> ```

This is implemented in practice by giving `f` a hidden extra argument telling it where to construct its return value.

## Question

Why are potentially-overlapping subobjects **not** subject to mandatory elision? There's no reason `f` couldn't construct its return value directly in the base class section of `D`.

Comment: One reason is that any padding a the end of C may be reused by members of D. [Is tail padding of a base class guaranteed not to be reused by a derived class if the base class is an aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72586619/is-tail-padding-of-a-base-class-guaranteed-not-to-be-reused-by-a-derived-class-i)

Comment: @BoP The members of D haven't been initialized yet, so I still don't see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant resources are

- [CWG 2403](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2403) which was just recently updated
- [Itanium CXX ABI bug report](https://github.com/itanium-cxx-abi/cxx-abi/issues/107), with an in-depth discussion including Richard Smith. (it's also mentioned this problem was brought to CWG's attention as early as 2016)
- [GCC Bug Report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104282)

A couple of points:

1. `f()` will invoke a complete object (C1) constructor, not a base object (C2) constructor. This immediately rules out copy elision for cases where `C` has virtual bases (in which case C1 != C2).
2. In other cases, for a copy (materialization) to be avoided, C1 would need to unconditionally leave the tail padding untouched, unless `C` was a POD (in Itanium's case). However, this is impractical to guarantee, since sometimes machine instructions are more efficient when including the padding, there are ABI considerations, etc.

Your objection

> The members of D haven't been initialized yet

isn't quite true, since virtual base classes are allocated at the end of the complete object:

```
struct A {
    char i = 5;
    A() {} // to prevent this being a POD for the purpose of layout
};
struct C {
    int j; char s;
    C() { /* ...*/ }
};
struct D : virtual A, C {
    D() : A(), C(f()) {}
};
```

Here, `A` immediately follows `C` in memory. We cannot know if C is going to be a base of a complete object with virtual bases later on, when generating code for f or C's ctors.
If we let `f` construct the base object, which *happens after `A` is constructed*, we may overwrite the re-used tail padding, which is where `i` is located.

I recommend reading the discussion in the second link above, as it also addresses tangential points and ways in which the wording may be changed to reflect current implementation practice.

Comment: According to "Itanium CXX ABI bug report",  "An implementation already can't store to the tail padding of an object if that object might be a base subobject of some other object." Therefore, A and C are not overlapped, indicating that there is no reused tail padding, isn't it?

Comment: A and C are [definitely overlapped](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a440af538dc3005). The point Richard was making was precisely that `f` is not allowed to store to the tail padding if `f` _did not know that the return object could be a base_, which is why copy elision is not applied in that case (such that f always knows it's a complete object and just calls the complete object ctor)